# What resources can help to find a good neighbourhood in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, relocation

How would I go to find a good neighbourhood in a new city in the UK?  [This lifehacker post](http://lifehacker.com/5909195/how-can-i-quickly-find-the-best-neighborhoods-in-any-cityand-the-best-hangouts-therein) links a number of sites with neighbourhood information, but it seems that all of them ([Streetadvisor](http://www.streetadvisor.com), [Walkscore](http://www.walkscore.com), and others) are available for the USA and perhaps a few other countries, but not for (most of) Europe.

I'm looking for general strategies on how to find good neighbourhoods.  Although "good" is subjective, crime levels, walkability, access to public transportation and facilities, and cost of living (buy or rent), are not.  Ideally what I'm looking for is an interactive map where I could rate how I prioritise a number of criteria, and then I would be presented with a heatmap for an index calculated accordingly.  Failing that, I welcome answers that list one or more of those properties.

I am looking specifically for south-central England (Oxfordshire/Berkshire area), but I welcome answers applying elsewhere.

Comment: Not convinced that this is an expats question - surely this is a problem faced by locals as well? Even someone moving within London has several dozen suburbs they may not know about.

Comment: I think MySociety's [Mapumental](https://mapumental.com/) might be want you want (but it isn't free). The produce [nifty heat maps like these example ones](https://www.mysociety.org/2006/03/04/travel-time-maps-and-their-uses/), which help you see travel times, costs etc

Comment: @MarkMayo I would expect locals have better knowledge of good or bad neighbourhoods than expats — although I concede that the problem does not really start or end at the international border.

Comment: You can edit your question to include a general region like 'Central London', or 'Greater London' or 'Home Counties', 'the Highlands', 'Devonshire' etc.

Answer (score 1):

[Zoopla](http://zoopla.co.uk) has pretty good statistics for neighbourhoods when you look at the properties, but I can't think of a way to search by those stats specifically.